# DrawerLayout tan sólo me permite un click

Tags: java, android, xml, android-drawerlayout

estoy trabajando con un drawer menú, y me estoy liando bastante.
Según a dónde clickee, en ciertas ocasiones me deja de funcionar los clicks.

El código es el siguientes:

```
     @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //Cerramos el toolbar

        fab_rankit.hide();

        if (id == R.id.nav_perfil) {
            Intent intent_perfil = new Intent(Principal_Activity.this, PerfilActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent_perfil);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_ayuda) {
//            getSupportActionBar().hide();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.drawer_layout, new SwipeFragment())
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_estadisticas) {
            fab_rankit.show();

            RelativeLayout fab_hide = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.fab_hide);
            fab_hide.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal_);
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.id_principalActivity, new EstadisticasFragment())
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_acercade) {

            layout_abierto = true;
            recien_abierto = false;

            acercaDe_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_invisible_acercaDe);
            acercaDe_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            acercaDe_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    fab_rankit.show();
                    acercaDe_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    layout_abierto = false;
                    recien_abierto = true;
                    fab_rankit.show();
                }
            });

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gestion) {
            fab_rankit.show();

            Intent intent_gestion = new Intent(Principal_Activity.this, CargarRankingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent_gestion);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_salir) {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();

            salir_layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_salir_invisible);
            salir_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layout_abierto = true;
            recien_abierto = false;

            ImageButton bt_continuar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.continuar_salir);
            bt_continuar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    salir_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    recien_abierto = true;
                    layout_abierto = false;

                    logout();

//                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
//                            .add(R.id.id_principalActivity, new SplashScreenSalir_Fragment())
//                            .addToBackStack(null)
//                            .commit();
                }
            });

            ImageButton bt_cancelar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.cancelar_salir);
            bt_cancelar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    fab_rankit.show();
                    getSupportActionBar().show();

                    salir_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    layout_abierto = false;
                    recien_abierto = true;
                }
            });

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Tengo repartido los layout en diferentes zonas (activity_principal, content principal). Parece ser que si hago click en alguna de las opciones, y tras ella no se recrea la actividad, como es el caso de logout en dónde no me hace click en las ventanas, o el caso de acercade dónde solo abre un layout extra, deja de funcionar el manú (se abre, pero no permite click. En cambio, si manejo el menú con el teclado, si hace click)

La aparicencia de mi menú es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Sabéis por qué podría ser?
Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Para cargar los fragment de las distintas opciones del menu debes definir el fragment y luego cargarlo en el contenedor principal

```
    if (fragment != null) {
        fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.contenedor_principal, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
```

Si haces un LOGOUT, el usuario no debe poder acceder al menu, por lo que deberias matar el navigationView, con un finish()

```
    Intent login = new Intent(this, Login.class);
    startActivity(login);
    //setResult(RESULT_RETORNO_RAIZ); //para eliminar datos que permiten pasarte el login
    finish();
```

En tu código no estas respetando esto, y estas iniciando actividades en lugar de cargar fragment en el contenedor